# jquery toggle on hover for multiple divs

Tags: jquery, hover, toggle

I have some divs with identical structure and i want to toggle when the mouse hovers the div so a hides and b shows:

```
<ul class="tweets">
    <li>
        <div class="a">
            <p>show a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="b">
            <p>show b</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="a">
            <p>show a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="b">
            <p>show b</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="a">
            <p>show a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="b">
            <p>show b</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tweet = $("ul.tweets .a");

    tweet.hover(function(){
        $('.a').toggle();
        $('.b').toggle();
    });

});
```

But this toggles ALL the divs and i only need to toggle one.I should use $(this) but i don't know how.How could i make this work?

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kpNY4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this -- assign the `hover` handler to the `li` instead of the `div` inside of it, then use `.find()` to locate the `div`s and toggle each one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tweet = $("ul.tweets li");

    tweet.hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.a').toggle()
            .end().find('.b').toggle();
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kpNY4/1/

Comment: it would be possible to fade the toggle so the transition looks softer?

Comment: Yes, see http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/ -- But that gets more complicated because you either need to (a) fade one out completely before the other fades in or (b) absolutely position one on top of the other in order to cross-fade them in the same place. Please submit a new question if you need help with that approach.

Comment: i've created another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157155/how-to-fade-the-toggle-so-the-transition-looks-softer)

Answer (score 0):

Should do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tweet = $("ul.tweets li");

    tweet.hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".a").toggle();
        $(this).find(".b").toggle();
    });

});
```

here is the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/kpNY4/2/