# how to fade the toggle so the transition looks softer

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade

How could i make the toggle transition look softer? I'm "toggling" 2 divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tweet = $("ul.tweets li");

    tweet.hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.a').toggle()
            .end().find('.b').toggle();
    });

});
```

this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kpNY4/1/)

Comment: @BNL... you just removed 'jQuery' term from the Q title. Now tell me... you use Google right? When you search for jQuery related questions... you type 'jQuery...' right? Well you just 'unhelped' lots of users browsing for answer to a similar Q (Using Google.)

Comment: @roXon actuallly, the most prominent tag will be prepended to the title so it still shows up as Jquery. Only problem is the header title which search engines has some sort of ranking on also

Comment: @Shawn. Yes I know that (up in the title stays 'jquery - ...'). Not what I'm talking about. It's the `<h1>` I'm worried about. It's just that this 'editor's *must erase*' arise in popularity. After some time it will be hard to find an answer browsing. Just thinking. I could be possibly wrong but I think that in the last period I'm mostly browsing in the SO browser - than googlin'

Comment: @roXon - The SO recommendation is to not put redundant tags in the title, unless it makes sense coversationally.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61059

Comment: @gilly3 ... I tried to pass trough all the comments and answers and no-one stops discussing the problem i mentioned above.

Comment: @roXon - Your concern seems to be SEO related.  I think it is a non-issue.  The proof is in the pudding: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+fade+toggle+smooth+transition  Top result already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).

**Edit:** If you absolutely position `.b` and relatively position `li`, you only need to toggle `.b`:

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kpNY4/8/

```
tweet.hover(function () {
    $(".b", this).fadeToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
li { position: relative; }
.b {
    display: none;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: this works but the two divs are visible at the same time so if they dont have the same size looks bad.

Comment: @Oterox - That should be fixable with CSS.  I can't address it though without seeing code that reproduces the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding and toggling:

```
tweet.hide('medium', function() {
 $(this).find('.a').toggle().end().find('.b').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery fadeIn ( http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ ) and fadeOut ( http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ ) does just that.